# Out of memory error while using Text::CSV_XS and reading multiple CSV files

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module

Below is my code to print unique Project list for which History is not empty.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS qw ( csv );

my $q = 0;
my $r = 0;
my @array1;
my @array2;
my @array3;
my %uniqueproject;
my @files = glob("*.csv");
foreach $s (@files) {
    open( my $fh, "<", "$s" ) or die "cannot open the file $!";
    my @aoh = @{ csv( in => $fh, headers => "auto" ) };
    foreach my $i (@aoh) {
        if ( defined( $aoh[$q]{History} ) ) {
            if ( $aoh[$q]{History} ne "" ) {
                $array1[$r] = $aoh[$q]{PROJECT};
                $array2[$r] = $aoh[$q]{IDENTIFIER};
                $r++;
            }
        }
        $q++;
    }
    close($fh);
}
foreach (@array1) {
    $uniqueproject{$_} = 1;
}
@array3 = keys(%uniqueproject);
foreach (@array3) {
    print $_. "\n";
}
```

The above code works fine if there is only single CSV in the folder. For multiple CSV files, I am getting an out of memory error. I cannot understand the reason for this error. Please let me know what is filling up the memory. If a `foreach` loop is not correct for iterating through files, suggest the correct loop to use.

My sample CSVs are

**test1.csv:**

```
"SEVERITY","DESCRIPTION","PROJECT","Attachments","priority","IDENTIFIER","STATUS","History","TITLE"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","123","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","124","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","125","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","126","pending","repeat","test csv"
```

**test2.csv:**

```
"SEVERITY","DESCRIPTION","PROJECT","Attachments","priority","IDENTIFIER","STATUS","History","TITLE"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskflafkdalsfjkasljfkldksajdfklsajkl","hadkf3","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","123","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf4","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","124","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf4","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","125","pending","repeat","test csv"
"3","fdlkfjalskfjlskfla
fkdalsfjkasljfkl
dksajdfklsajkl","hadkf4","dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk","4","126","pending","repeat","test csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on what you mean by 'unique' projects, but am assuming that you are trying to extract all the IDs and projects for which there is a value in `History`. If it is something else , you'll have to edit your question to clarify the situation. Unfortunately the test data you have provided is rubbish so I'm not sure whether `IDENTIFIER` and `PROJECT` are both unique -- a couple of lines with different IDs have the same PROJECT name. I will assume that `IDENTIFIER` is a unique identifier.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature ':5.10';

use Text::CSV_XS qw ( csv );

# we will store project info in this hash
my %unique;
my @files = glob("*.csv");

for my $s (@files) {
    open (my $fh, "<","$s") or die "cannot open the file $!";
    my @aoh = @{csv (in => $fh, headers => "auto")};

    # go through the results...
    for (@aoh) {
        # if 'History' is defined and has some content (\w tests for alphanumeric chars)
        if ($_->{History} && $_->{History} =~ /\w/) {
            # add it to the hash of unique projects
            # store the ID as the key and the project name as the value
            $unique{ $_->{IDENTIFIER} } = $_->{PROJECT};
        }
    }
    close ($fh);
}

# now you can go through the hash of projects and print out the ID and project name
for (keys %unique) {
    say "id: $_; project: $unique{$_}";
}
```

Your code wasn't working for a slightly subtle reason to do with how you were checking for projects. You checked through the array of hashes produced by parsing the files after each file was parsed, but were using a mix of numerical indexes and variables to refer to what should have been the same entity. For example:

```
foreach my $i (@aoh) {
    if ( defined( $aoh[$q]{History} ) ) {
        if ( $aoh[$q]{History} ne "" ) {
```

In the `foreach` loop, you don't need to refer to `$aoh[$q]` -- it is already referred to by `$i`, so you can just write `if ( defined $i{History} )`. Using the numerical index becomes a problem because you don't reset it to 0 after the first file, so when you start looking at the results for file 2, `$q` isn't 0 -- it's already set at the number of results from the first file. `if (defined $aoh[$q]{History})` looks at `$aoh[6]{History}` instead of `$aoh[0]{History}` when it runs for the first time on file 2 results! Unfortunately, when you search for `$aoh[6]{History}`, Perl automatically assumes that `$aoh[6]` exists, and will create it if it doesn't exist.

You can get a nice visualisation of what's happening if you amend your code to the following:

```
foreach $s (@files) {
    open( my $fh, "<", "$s" ) or die "cannot open the file $!";
    my @aoh = @{ csv( in => $fh, headers => "auto" ) };
    say "Parsed file $s; found " . @aoh . " entries";

    # add an accumulator 
    my $acc = 0;
    foreach my $i (@aoh) {
        say "looking at array entry $acc, aoh length: " . @aoh . "; q: $q; r: $r";
        if ( defined( $aoh[$q]{History} ) ) {
            if ( $aoh[$q]{History} ne "" ) {
                $array1[$r] = $aoh[$q]{PROJECT};
                $array2[$r] = $aoh[$q]{IDENTIFIER};
                $r++;
            }
        }
        $acc++;
        $q++;
        # die after 20 iterations or we'll be here all night!
        die if $acc == 20;
    }
    close($fh);
}
```

Partial output:

```
Parsed file file2.csv; found 10 entries
looking at array entry 0, aoh length: 10; q: 12; r: 4
looking at array entry 1, aoh length: 13; q: 13; r: 4
looking at array entry 2, aoh length: 14; q: 14; r: 4
looking at array entry 3, aoh length: 15; q: 15; r: 4
looking at array entry 4, aoh length: 16; q: 16; r: 4
looking at array entry 5, aoh length: 17; q: 17; r: 4
looking at array entry 6, aoh length: 18; q: 18; r: 4
looking at array entry 7, aoh length: 19; q: 19; r: 4
looking at array entry 8, aoh length: 20; q: 20; r: 4
looking at array entry 9, aoh length: 21; q: 21; r: 4
looking at array entry 10, aoh length: 22; q: 22; r: 4
```

The array `@aoh` is getting steadily longer with each entry that you check!

Comment: I cannot use     if ( defined $i{History} ), instead i may use if      (defined $i->{History})